# Filter documents with more than one date in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents with a field that contains multiple dates.

```
"release_date" : [
"2015-07-10",
"2015-07-13",
"2015-07-26",
"2015-07-27"
]
```

I would like to **filter all documents with at least a date greater than a another given date**.

I was able to use range filter when the document just had one date

```
{
    "constant_score": {
        "filter": {
            "range" : {
                "release_date" : {
                    "gte": "2012-01-01",
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But now that I have more than one date, I don't find the way to achieve a similar result. Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Please show what you've done so far, it'll be easier for everyone to picture what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you're "release_date" field is properly mapped to a date object.  The following example works for what you're trying to do:

```
PUT test1

PUT /test1/_mapping/type1
{
    "type1" : {
        "properties" : {
            "release_date" : {"type" : "date"}
        }
    }
}

POST test1/type1
{
  "release_date" : [
    "2014-03-28",
    "2010-03-28",
    "2011-03-28"
    ]
}

GET test1/type1/_search
{
  "query": {
"filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "release_date": {
            "gte": "2013-01-01"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```